# Bindservice requires enable set to be true

Tags: android, service

My Bindservice does not get bind and start properly until the enable attribute in Manifest set to be true.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#enabled), set enable to be true allows the system to instantiated.

I was wondering what is the meaning of set the enable to be false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that nothing can start that service, until you, at runtime, enable it (using `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`).